# Accessing Provenance of Style Applied to Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, styles, stylesheet

I would like to be able to query with Javascript where a particular CSS property was assigned to an element. For instance, if an element's height is 40px, I would like to know if this was assigned via an stylesheet, whether it was assigned via an inline rule, or whether it is an automatic result of the layout engine.

For some properties, like "height" I can't seem to be able to tell the difference by just looking at the computed style or the style property of the element itself.

It turns out that I can detect inline style by parsing through style attributes, and I can find some stylesheets by parsing through the documents stylesheet and rules arrays.

My current method of checking stylesheets/inline rules would work, but fails because Javascript cannot access stylesheets loaded from different domains/protocols due to the same origin policy.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!
Jeff

Comment: Is this just for debugging or do oyu need to do this programatically for some reason? If its jsut debug then you can get this information from Firebug or Developer Tools.

Comment: need to access it programmatically from a JS library included on pages that I don't control, which may include external stylesheets from different origins  (not debugging)